# ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 716: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check.... at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Have created a .sql file for pincodes. It is a huge file so cant edit it on a line to line basis,so edited using vi regex..,

```
CREATE TABLE pincode(
officename VARCHAR(100),
pincode INT (6),
officeType VARCHAR(100),
Deliverystatus VARCHAR(100),
divisionname VARCHAR(100),
regionname VARCHAR(100),
circlename VARCHAR(100),
Taluk VARCHAR(100),
Districtname VARCHAR(100),
statename VARCHAR(100));
```

(**following is the line showing the below mentioned error**)

```
INSERT INTO pincode (officename,pincode,officeType,Deliverystatus,divisionname,regionname,circlename,Taluk,Districtname,statename)
VALUES('Komaravalli B.O','506355','B.O','Delivery','Hanamkonda','Hyderabad','Andhra Pradesh','Cherial','Warangal','ANDHRA PRADESH');
```

Error I am getting on running the file:-

**ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 716: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'B.O','506355','B.O','Delivery','Hanamkonda','Hyderabad','Andhra Pradesh','Cheria' at line 1**

Comment: The statements/sample insert you have shown are can't produce this error [*See demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88630/1) there must b something other which is producing this error may be you have a single quote for the value of `officename`

Comment: In sqlfiddle it looks OK. Are you sure that this query runs in problems?

Comment: You are most likely executing a broken query before this one.

Comment: [**working fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6eaf)

Comment: pincode field in your table structure is INT. Please INSERT an INT value